# Running and debugging program from Visual Studio in virtual machine like VirtualPC or VirtualBox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, virtual-pc

I have program that I want to test on clean Windows installation. For now I have image in VirtualBox and I start program from shared folder, but this is not comfortable and I can't debug.

For debugging I found that I can use [Remote Debugging Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf8k2h6a.aspx), but still I want to automate whole process, especially uploading application on virtual machine.

I thought that VirtualPC would be better then VirtualBox, because this application was created by Microsoft. Unfortunately I can't find any info how to connect them.

**EDIT:**
After research: only possibility is to treat virtual machine as remote computer. There is no easier way. Project need to be published to VM using shared folders. After configuring in Visual Studion new release type for remote debugging all triggers automaticly and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

1.Place the program in a pre-defined shared directory, such that it is immediately visible to the virtual machine after redeployment.

2.Remote debugger invokation can be automated - all the parameters, such as users allowed to debug can be passed on the command line.

VirtualBox is quite OK for this task, as it allows you to replace only the disk image with clean one, while leaving the setup, including shared directories intact. I am sure VirtualPC also allows such a thing, but choosing it just because it's also written by Microsoft does not seem like a valid consideration here.

Comment: After research I found out that this is only option. I need to share this project by shared folders and start remote debugger. Then configure Visual Studio pointing at proper path in vm. I suggested VirtualPC because I thought that both products are from Microsoft and can integrate somehow without all of this.